# Ensure knots in spline regression are placed at correct positions

Tags: r, time-series, regression, spline, cubic-spline

I have time-series data as:

```
library(xts)
library(splines)
set.seed(123)
time <- seq(as.POSIXct("2015-09-01"),as.POSIXct("2015-09-01 23:59:59"),by="hour")
ob <- xts(rnorm(length(time),150,5),time))
```

The object `ob` is hourly time-series object. Now, I want to do spline regression over it. I want to place knots at 7 A.M and 4 P.M.
Does the following statement in `R` ensure this

```
ns(ob,knots = c(7,16)) # 7 corresponds to 7 AM and 16 corresponds to 4 PM
```

Also, how should I cross check that knots are placed at the said times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sort of on the wrong track. It seems you want to regress observation on time, so you should really feed time index rather than observations `ob` to `ns`.

```
y <- as.vector(ob)    ## observations
x <- 1:24    ## 24 hourse
```

Then consider a model:

```
y ~ ns(x, knots = c(7, 16))
```

As you can see, there is really no need to use "xts" object here.

---

`ns` generates a design matrix. Have a check on

```
X <- ns(x, knots = c(7, 16))
```

You will see attributes:

```
#attr(,"degree")
#[1] 3
#attr(,"knots")
#[1]  7 16
#attr(,"Boundary.knots")
#[1]  1 24
#attr(,"intercept")
#[1] FALSE
#attr(,"class")
#[1] "ns"     "basis"  "matrix"
```

The "knots" field gives you information on location of internal knots.